# Resizing Bootable USB Partition

Tags: live-usb

I am trying to resize the usable partition of my USB flash drive, as even though there is 14gb of 'free space', ubuntu can only use 1.8gb. However, when ever I go into Disks or use Gparted the option to change the size of partition 1 is either grayed out or says 'udisks-error-quark 0'. Is there any way around this?

Comment: If it's a *live* system it'll be RO (read-only) and all changes are made to RAM (copy-on-write) thus lost on shutdown/reboot. If it's in-use, you need to `umount` first. It's easiest to install to a second thumb-drive, or re-write the thumb-drive in a manner that uses persistence utilizing the extra space.  You didn't mention release details so this is generic advice.

Comment: Please tell us how you created the bootable system in your USB flash drive, which tool you used. And please tell us which version of Ubuntu it is. Otherwise we can only guess how to solve your problem.

Comment: Fairly easy when you know how. I don't have the experience in that regard as you two do @C.S.Cameron & Sudodus !

Answer (score 2):

### Creating a NTFS Data Partition on a Startup Disk Creator, balenaEtcher or Similar ISO9660 USB

Since 19.10 the process of cloning an OS to USB as done by Startup Disk Creator, creates a casper-rw partition.

This partition can be used for persistence by pressing shift at boot and esc, then F6 and esc again. then typing a space and the word "persistent".

This must be done every boot where persistence in wanted.

It is possible to modify the ISO file used by SDC to include the word persistence into grub, but it is not easy.

If the Ubuntu install is mainly needed for installing Ubuntu, the casper-rw partition can easily be converted to a NTFS or FAT32 partition, that can be used for Data storage by both Linux and Windows.

**Procedure**

- Run Startup Disk Creator or Etcher to create Live 19.10, 20.04, (or later), USB.
- Boot new Live USB to activate casper-rw partition, then Power Off.
- Reboot the Live USB **toram**. (press shift when booting, hit F6 and type a space and toram).
- Unmount casper-rw partition using Disks.
- Open Terminal and run:

`sudo mkfs.ntfs -f -L data /dev/sdx3`

For NTFS Partition or for FAT32:

`sudo mkfs.vfat -n data /dev/sdx3`

were x is the drive number of the new Live USB

[image]

The drive should now have the original data space minus the size of the OS ISO.

Edit:

**mkusb-plug** can also be used to turn the space into Data space or into Persistence space that will save the work done on the USB from boot to boot.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/plug

Comment: *Since 19.10 the process of cloning an OS to USB as done by Startup Disk Creator, creates a casper-rw partition.* I've just used it to clone 20.04.1 and didn't create a data partition, just left empty space.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity; The above should be able to turn that empty space into a Data partition. Experimenting with Groovy 20.10, cloning also creates empty space, not an ext "writable" partition. I was able to format that space FAT32, NTFS and ext4. None of which were readable by Windows, but were by Nautilus.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity, The Startup Disk Creator does not create a partition with the label 'casper-rw' or 'writable'. The partition is created by 19.10 and 20.04.x LTS, the first time you boot from the USB drive [created by the Startup Disk Creator]. This is problematic in many cases (but not always) with the current daily live Groovy iso files.

Comment: @sudodus: The empty space seems to format as FAT32, NTFS or ext4 okay with Groovy. I was able to make a persistent partition using:  `sudo mkfs.ext4 -L writable /dev/sdx3` when I pressed `e` at the boot menu and added `persistent` I got a persistent session. Is it working with mkusb-plug? I guess I should give that a try.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron, Yes, **mkusb-plug from the unstable PPA worked, when I tried with a Groovy current daily iso file** a couple of days ago. (That is, provided that a cloned iso file worked live in that computer, so it worked in all my test computers except a Lenovo V130 in UEFI mode).